# Can I add a wildcard to TinyMCE domain whitelist?

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to use TinyMCE inside of salesforce. The domain is usually dynamic due to name space.

Also do I need the API key to use the open source version?

Answer (score 0):

You only need an API key if you plan on using TinyMCE from the Tiny Cloud platform.  If you download and deploy the self hosted open source code there is no API key or need to register domains.  If they domains all fall under some basic domain

- randomdomain1.salesforce.com
- randomdomain2.salesforce.com

You can just register salesforce.com as your domain and any subdomain thereof will also be accepted.

Comment: If I dont add the api key, i get the following error: 

`This domain is not registered with Tiny Cloud.  Please see the quick start guide or create an account``

I used yarn to self host tinyMCE

Comment: If you are getting that message you are not self hosting TinyMCE - that would only happen if you are using TinyMCE from the Cloud platform. Did you use one of our wrappers for something like React or Vue?  If so you may have installed the wrapper via yarn but TinyMCE itself is (by default) pulled from our Cloud platform.

Comment: Yes, I use the React wrapper. Can you direct to where I can remove that default?

Comment: If you first load TinyMCE the wrapper will use the existing TinyMCE as opposed to loading TinyMCE from the Cloud platform. You can pull TinyMCE via NPM as well and load it as described here:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/

Comment: You could also just load it in the head of your main page via a <script> tag.